# regex for regex result or twice regex

Tags: regex

i want to select all money numbers (red) and this is [regex which doesn't work](https://regex101.com/r/00aI5v/1)
[image: Text]

I can [improve regex](https://regex101.com/r/UDqYXZ/2) so that it'll select all numbers ranges like this 
[image: Text]

May I use some post select regex to remove all dates/time from it? 
like where it 
doesn't contain '/' 
and double '.' 
and ':'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(?<!\d[:\/.])\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?(?![.\/:]?\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tYcOdV/3)

**Regex details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\d[:\/.])` - no digit + `:`, `/` or `.` allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:,\d+)*` - zero or more occurrences of `,` and 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional occurrence of `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?![.\/:]?\d)` - no optional `.`, `/` or `:` followed with a digit are allowed immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: I understood `900p` should not be matched. Ok, I fixed it.

Comment: 900 wasn't found, but could you please refer me to docs regarding this stuff better?

Comment: we also can use \w in allowance restrictions so that this date also won't go 25-JUL-19 \b(?<!\w[:\/.])\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?(?![.\/:]?\w)

Comment: @AndrewSmirnov How come `900` was not found? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tYcOdV/3) again. Yes, you may replace `\d` with `\w` in the lookarounds to further precise it for your cases, we only saw a few.

Comment: 900 was found, agree. but to remove findings in date like this 25-JUL-19 https://regex101.com/r/rR4C3I/1 I made pretty complex regex \b(?<![:\/-])(?<!\d[:\/.-])\d{1,8}(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?(?![.\/:-]?\d)(?![\/:-]) https://regex101.com/r/Lx8X8Q/1 because in code 900p (kotlin) 900 was not found. can I simplify it?

Comment: @AndrewSmirnov So, you write the code in Kotlin? You may match and discard dates and match & capture the numbers you need. Like in [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rR4C3I/2), `(?<!\d)\d{1,2}-\w{3}-\d{1,2}(?!\d)|\b(?<!\d[:\/.])(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)(?![.\/:]?\d)`. It will work for you if you remove, or extract matches, let me know if you need help with the code.

Comment: yes, it's Kotlin somehow in 900p 900 is not found in Kotlin when I used \b(?<!\w[:\/.])\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?(?![.\/:]?\w) - for removal dates like this 25-JUL-19, so  I complicated regex so that in 900p 900 is found in Kotlin, but it's quite complex. Q: can we simplify it to work in Kotlin \b(?<![:\/-])(?<!\d[:\/.-])\d{1,8}(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?(?![.\/:-]?\d)(?![\/:-])

Comment: @AndrewSmirnov Yes, it is possible, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rR4C3I/3) and the [Kotlin demo](https://rextester.com/XHJ18124).

Comment: thank you very much! kotlin texting tool is very useful! finally removed word boundary and added negative sums support, along with :sum, .sum https://regex101.com/r/rR4C3I/4